# Interpretation of dual mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand duality from "Linear Algebra Done Right" 3rd edition by Axler. However I reached a point that didn't seem too evident in the book, so I would appreciate if somebody pointed out what I'm missing here.

Let $T'\in \mathcal{L}(W',V')$ be the dual map of a linear map $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$. By definition of dual map, $T'(\phi)= \phi \circ T$ for $\phi \in W'$. By definition of dual space, $W'=\mathcal{L}(W,\mathbf{F})$.

For all $w \in$ range $T$, $v \in V$ and $\phi \in W'$,$\,\,\,\,$ $T': \phi(w)\to\phi(Tv)$.

Does it mean that $W'=V'$ if $T$ is surjective?

Comment: This is no different from the question: If $T\colon V\to W$ is injective , is $V=W$? All we can say (assuming finite dimensions) is that $\dim V\le \dim W$. The vector spaces may have no relation to one another whatsoever.

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by $T': \phi(w)\to\phi(Tv)$. Maybe you want to say that $(\phi\circ T)v=\phi(Tv)$?

Comment: @Masacroso yes, is that equality right?

Comment: @user3047 of course: the equality is a consequence of the definition of $T'$, just note that $\phi\circ T\in V'$

Comment: Of course it is correct, it is the definition of composition (or multiplication) of linear transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a linear map $\textsf{T}:\textsf{V}\to\textsf{W}$. When we say that $\phi\in \textsf{W}^*$ (the dual space of $\textsf{W}$) we are saying that $\phi$ is a linear map from $\textsf{W}$ to the field $F$.
And the part where you're confused is in the definition of
$$\textsf{T}': \textsf{W}^* \to \textsf{V}^*$$
given by $\textsf{T}'(\phi)=\phi \circ \textsf{T}$. What you have to understand is that $\phi \circ \textsf{T}$ is also a linear functional from $\textsf{V}$ to the field $F$ because it does not make much sense of what you're talking about.

Comment: i see. maybe i meant to ask if the range of a functional in V' is equal to the range of a functional in W' if T is surjective, since each $\phi$ would take the same input w=Tv from both spaces?

Comment: Note that, the only vector subspaces of $F$ are the zero subspace $\{0\}$ or itself. And since the range of any linear transformation is a subspace of the codomain, in this case, $F$, since we are talking about linear functionals, we can say that in general, yes, given $\phi \in \textsf{W}^*$ and $\psi \in \textsf{V}^*$, $\operatorname{range}(\phi)=\operatorname{range}(\psi)$.